# How to Install the Visual Studio Emulator for Android on Windows 10

Tags: android, android-layout, visual-studio-2013, android-emulator, windows-phone-8-emulator

I try to install the Visual Studio Emulator for Android on Windows 10 and visual studio 2017 but I see the [following error message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx) when it try to install the emulator

[image]

> this computer does not support the windows phone emulator which requires the 64-bit edition of windows 8.1 pro and a computer that supports Huper-V

So I know the problem is the [System Requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx), for install the Visual Studio Emulator for Android. we need 6 GB RAM and etc hardware requirements,
But my system dose not has 6 GB RAM.
Is there any solution for this problem that I can install the Visual Studio Emulator for Android? 
Or I should add 6 GB RAM and another Hardware requirement to my system?

Comment: What are your system's specs? You don't have 6GB of ram, do you run x64 windows pro? Do you have hyper-v enabled in the windows features? Does your system have the required virtualization options enabled in the system BIOS?

Comment: This are my system specification 
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3130M CPU @2.60GHz
Installed memory (RAM): 4.00 GB
System type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
How I can run  x64 windows pro?
How I can get the hyper-v enabled in the windows features?
How to find the hyper-v enabled in the windows features?

Comment: Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-requirements and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Comment: If I Install Hyper-V on Windows 10 on my system then  I can instal the Emulator for Android on Windows 10 with out error ? 

Actually right now I faced to this error  (this computer does not support the windows phone emulator which requires the 64-bit edition of windows 8.1 pro and a computer that supports Huper-V) 
when I try to install the  Emulator for Android
please help  what I should do?